# Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()' error with experimental-gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I have to use experimental-gradle for native code debug and "provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'" in build.gradle, but it seems that the experimental version does not support provided grammar, with error message "Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()'".

For experimental-gradle, I am using "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-beta3", and main build.gradle was posted [here](https://gist.github.com/e-snail/d82e2284e00cfc21400adf46530ff8b1)

So any solution ?